# Connecting to a REST webservice in C#

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I am not familiar with REST webservices, but I am trying to get a response from one of them in a C# application.

I am trying to connect to the webservice and authenticate my application to get a token. For this, I have an URL, a login and a password.

When I call the authentication method with cURL tool, I get a « success :true»  answer, followed with the token string.
But when I try to do the same with my C# code, I always get a « success :false» answer and no token.

Can somebody help me to understand what is missing in my C# code to get the correct answer ? Thank you.

The cURL request (given by the webservice owner) is:
`curl -X POST -d "{\"user\":\"mylogin\",\"pwd\":\"mypassword\"}" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" http://webserviceURL/authenticate`

My code is the following : (restlogin, restpassword and resturl are three strings and get the correct values for the connection. The resulting string is obtained in the variable nammed token).

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resturl + "authenticate");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(restlogin, restpassword);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Timeout = 30000;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;


            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                    token = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    response.Close();

                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you add your cURL-request, too? Maybe you're calling it in a slightly different way.

Comment: If it is a RESTful service it will use different verbs. Are you sure the auth method is using POST as a verb and not GET?

Comment: The cURL request (given by the webservice owner) is :                            
    curl -X POST -d "{\"user\":\"mylogin\",\"pwd\":\"mypassword\"}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://webserviceURL/authenticate

Comment: Yes, the webservice specifications say that the verb to use is POST.

Comment: You are not sending your credentials in the request body. With `request.Credentials` you're setting the Authentication Header in your `HttpRequest`.

Comment: Can you tell me how to provide the credentials in the request body ? Thank you.

Comment: Use `Request.Write()` shoud do the trick.

Comment: @BrunoBarral Please see my answer.

Comment: Thank for your help. I thought that supplying credentials in header was enough. I will look a Request.Write().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment to the question, you are not sending your credentials in the request body. With `request.Credentials` you're setting the Authentication Header in your `HttpRequest`.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resturl + "authenticate");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Timeout = 30000;
        request.ReadWriteTimeout = 30000;
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

// Set your Response body
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"user\":\"" + restlogin + "\"," +
                  "\"pwd\":\"" + restpassword + "\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream())
     {
         StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);
         token = reader.ReadToEnd();
         reader.Close();
         reader.Dispose();
         response.Close();

     }
}
```

Comment: I had a try and everything works fine now. Thank you very much Aurril for the code sample !

Comment: @BrunoBarral Please accept the answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, i am new at StackOverflow and did not know how to do that. I accepted it now.